# Would directly copying a mongodb database causes problems?

Tags: git, mongodb

We push our project to git and the mongodb data files are also in the committed directories.

We found that when pull the project onto another machine, we failed to insert document into a collection. However, if we drop the collection and recreate the collection with the same name, the insertion success. 
Why we failed to insert and why we succeed again by recreate the collection?

I am new to mongodb, I need your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you cleanly shutdown the `mongod` in question, copying the contents of `--dbpath` is not a problem. Actually, it is considered a valid practice for backup purposes.

When copying the files of a running instance, you are copying lock files and journaling data which get deleted during a clean shutdown. This may prevent write access to the collections.

When you delete the collection, all those metafiles are reset and of course you can insert then.

So what you have to do:

1. Shut down the first instance *cleanly*
2. Add, commit and push the contents of `dbpath`
3. Restart the first instance
4. Shutdown the target instance if running
5. Pull the data
6. Restart the target instance